# How to get files and subfolders of a folder

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a simple bash script which will echo all the files from a folder, including subfolders. The following is my code. But the output I am getting is just ls $fromFolder

```
#! /bin/bash

fromFolder="~/proj/activex"
toFolder="~/proj/outgoing"

files='ls $fromFolder'

for file in $files 
do
    echo $file
done
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `ls` command here. You can simply replace your for loop as:

```
for file in ~/proj/outgoing/*
do
   echo $file
done
```

Comment: It works. But when I used a variable to store the outgoing folder path and then use it it doesn't work. The following is the code I tried. outgoingFolder="~/proj/outgoing/*" for file in $outgoingFolder do...

Comment: Putting the '*' or other metacharacters in double quotes prevents their expansion.  use `for file in "$dir"/*; do ...; done`

Comment: Thanks @JoshCartwright. I think OP got answer to his comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
find $fromfolder -print
```

will print all of the files and subdirectories in $fromfolder.

This lists regular files

`find $fromfolder -print -type f`

This lists directories

`find $fromfolder -print -type d`

In you code --this has a problem
    `files='ls $fromFolder'`

`$fromfolder` will never be "translated" into its value by bash because of the single quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use double quotes instead of singles, which will allow the shell to expand the fromFolder variable:

```
files="ls $fromFolder"
```

Although anubhava's solution is better

Comment: This still doesn't make `files` a list of the names of files contained in `$fromFolder`.